# Identify a comic where Scrooge McDuck uses a substance to convert liquids into gel like solids

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm trying to find an Uncle Scrooge story where he has some substance that converts liquids into a gel-like solids and at the same time reduces their volume significantly.

He uses one drop of this substance to make a tanker's volume of oil into a gel which can be transported by a small ship. I believe he also solidified the sea to get lost treasures.

This gel can be cut and they gang cut water like salami for demonstration! 
I've read it in Greek btw.

Ι read it in the 1990s but it was a gift from an older kid.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Are you slightly mis-remembering [_The Universal Solvent_](http://alexmagnus.free.fr/Picsou/51%20-%20The%20Universal%20Solvent.pdf) run? It's a similar story line but instead the solvent converts any substance, except diamonds, into dust.

Answer (score 11):

This story was first published as "**Zio paperone e l'acqua concentrata**" in 1977 [3]. It was written by Giorgio Pezzin and drawn by Giorgio Cavazzano [4]. I remember the story and can verify your description, but see also [4,5] for a short italian-language description of the story.

[image]

Translation: "*It remains drinkable, but you can also slice it like a salami*"

As you can guess from the names of the creators, this story came from the "italian school" of Disney stories. They had artists with distinct drawing styles, their own story themes, typically "fantastic" rather than slice-of-life and a slightly different set of recurring characters than the US comics. For instance, they frequently used the US character "John D. Rockerduck" and their own invention "Paperinik", which is a Donald Duck version of Batman. (The character was later retconned into a future-duckburg relying heavily on elements borrowed from anime) See [5] for more on Italian disney comics.

In Norway and possibly elsewhere, the Italian comics were serialized in thick pocket books while the US comics went into a larger format weekly magazine. The story in question was published in the Norwegian Donald Pocket No. 70 in 1986, with the title "Mettende vann", translating as "hearty/filling water". The original italian title translates as "Uncle Scrooge and the concentrated water" but I'm unable to determine the official english title.

[image]

Second panel: "concentrated oil can be transported without pipelines!"

[3] I'm grateful for Francesco Stajano to include the source of the picture in his review of Pezzin's work: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~fms27/disney/2009-stajano-pezzin-saggio.pdf

[4] See bibliography at: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~fms27/disney/cavazzano/

[5] Francesco Stajano has also written in english about italian disney, including the story in question: https://www.scribd.com/document/30748070/disney-comics-from-Italy

Comment: Could you edit in how this matches with evidence, at the moment all we've really got to go on is your word.

Comment: Mettende Vann = "Saturated water".

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot: You're right, I can do better. Re-wrote with more sources :-)

Comment: Much much better and worthy of an upvote. Great find.